# Extract sub-Graph from Large Networkx graph with any selected node?

Tags: networkx, graph-theory, graph-visualization, subgraph, pyvis

I have a large network graph below which is made with the `pyvis` library.
The HTML loading/rendering time is very high and it takes more time to load.

[image]

I want to extract the subgraphs individually like

[image]

I want to extract any subgraph marked in the above image by selecting the **node**. In simple instead of plotting the entire network, I want to plot the one selected subgraph.

Is there a python function that extracts the subgraphs from the entire network?

Comment: *"by selecting the **node**."*. What's "the node"? What node?

Comment: any node in the network graph as input

Comment: How would the algorithm figure out which subgraph to extract for a given node? Is there a precomputed list of subgraphs, with at most one subgraph per node?

Comment: @Stef, Pardon me for being not clear.  I'm very new to graph analysis. I have a large network, from that I need to extract subgraph.

Comment: What subgraph do you need to extract?

Comment: Any one of the graphs from the entire network. For example, any one of the rounded from the second image?

Comment: Any subgraph? If I input node A, how will you choose between all the possible subgraphs A, AB, AC, ABC, AD, ABD, ACD, ABCD, etc?

Comment: Maybe with the highest node connections/degrees....

Answer (score 0):

In the networkx library, the function `networkx.algorithms.clique.cliques_containing_node` returns all the maximal cliques containing a given node.

#### Relevant documentation

- [networkx.algorithms.clique.cliques_containing_node](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.cliques_containing_node.html#networkx.algorithms.clique.cliques_containing_node)
- [Wikipedia: Clique (graph theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory))

#### Example use

##### Building a graph

```py
import networkx as nx
import itertools as it
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_nodes_from(list(range(8)))
G.add_edges_from(it.combinations(range(0,4),2))
G.add_edges_from(it.combinations(range(4,7),2))
G.add_edges_from([(3,4), (6,7)])

print(G.nodes)
# NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))

print(G.edges)
# EdgeView([(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6), (6, 7)])

print(G.adj)
# AdjacencyView({0: {1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}}, 1: {0: {}, 2: {}, 3: {}}, 2: {0: {}, 1: {}, 3: {}}, 3: {0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 4: {}}, 4: {5: {}, 6: {}, 3: {}}, 5: {4: {}, 6: {}}, 6: {4: {}, 5: {}, 7: {}}, 7: {6: {}}})

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph with small cliques]

##### Calling `cliques_containing_node` on our graph

```py
print(nx.algorithms.clique.cliques_containing_node(G, [0, 4, 7]))
# {0: [[3, 0, 1, 2]], 4: [[3, 4], [5, 4, 6]], 7: [[6, 7]]}
```

Here the function `nx.algorithms.clique.cliques_containing_node` tells us that node 0 is in the maximal clique [0,1,2,3]; node 4 is in two maximal cliques, [3,4] and [5,4,6]; and node 7 is in the maximal clique [6,7].